# How to get changes done to mysql table during a time interval?

Tags: mysql, database, data-warehouse

I am essentially creating a data warehouse.
For warehouse to remain consistent with the source data, I have to pull changes daily from the source mysql DBs.
My problem is that, in some source mysql tables, there is no 'lastupdated' equivalent columns.

How can i pull changes in this scenario?

Comment: You can't easily do this, and if you really expect to have this requirement long term, then you should seriously consider adding some kind of date/timestamp column to the table(s).

Comment: If you want to do differential loading (i.e. only loading changed rows) one viable solution is to use some other column or combination of columns to detect changes to the tables. For example, you could record the last ID inserted yesterday and next day you'll only load rows with ID > lastInsertedId. Whether this is viable or not depends on the tables, you should post their structure otherwise its hard to understand your problem. If this isn't possible, you can always fully load all tables every day, but this will be slower and inefficient, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

In a data warehouse, in order to capture the changes in the target system, there has to be a way to identify the changed, new records at the source side. This is normally done with the help of some Flag or Lastupdated column. But if neither of these is present & if the table is small, you can consider truncating & reloading the entire data from source to the target. But this may not be very feasible for large tables.

You can also refer some other techniques mentioned in the below blog-:
https://www.hvr-software.com/blog/change-data-capture/